In blmer, is sigma variable random-effect covariance, and why would cov(r,c)var(r) = var(c)?
As the title says, I have two questions regarding the blmer() models in R. I have tried to get firm understanding about the topic using the documentation and literature, but I am still a little bit unsure.
1) To fit blmer() models on two-level data, if I define a custom density function for the cov.prior, what is exactly the sigma variable the function receives? I assume it is the random-effect covariance, as the blme documentation clearly states about the cov.prior: "Imposes a prior over the covariance of the random effects/modeled coefficients". This sigma is iterated through a several values until an appropriate model fit is found. I believe the sigma values are used to pick up the corresponding prior probabilities for the random-effect covariance from the given cov.prior density function. Am I right?
2) If the sigma is indeed the random-effect covariance, then why it can be multiplied with the residual variance to get the cluster variance (like this way: cov(r,c)var(r) = var(c); where r refers to residual and c to cluster)? I haven't found sources for this kind of property of the covariances and variances, or have I missed something? A literature source for the property would be helpful.
Below is some code to experiment and reproduce my observations. See the comments for further information.
    #From sessionInfo():
    #R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
    #Running under: Windows
    #[1] blme_1.0-5
    
    #Define data parameters for test data
    clusters <- 8
    clustersize <- 3
    measurements <- clusters*clustersize
    SD1 <- 4
    SD2 <- 2
    
    #Create clustered test data with residual variation
    set.seed(123)
    data <- data.frame(dependent = rnorm(measurements, 0, SD1),
                      predictor = c(rep(c("control", "test"), each = measurements/2)),
                      cluster = rep(c(1:clusters), each = clustersize))
    
    #Add random effects
    randomeffects <- rnorm(clusters, 0, SD2)
    data$dependent <- data$dependent + rep(randomeffects, each = clustersize)
    
    head(data)
    #  dependent predictor cluster
    #1 -3.491981   control       1
    #2 -2.170788   control       1
    #3  4.984755   control       1
    #4 -3.091353   control       2
    #5 -2.856236   control       2
    #6  3.486873   control       2
    
    boxplot(dependent ~ cluster, data)
    
    #In this dataframe we will collect the last iterated sigma values and two-level variances
    sigmascan <- data.frame(latestsigma = numeric(),
                           varresid = numeric(),
                           varclust = numeric())

library(blme)    

    #Use narrow normal priors to incrementally move the sigma during multiple model fits
    for (priormean in c(0:20)/10) {
    
    #Define the custom prior function which also prints and stores the iterated sigma values
    prior <- function(sigma) {
       message(sigma)
       sigmastore <<- sigma
       return(dnorm(sigma, mean = priormean, sd = 0.055))
    }
    
    #Fit the blmer() model with the custom covariance-prior function with default settings
    model <- blmer(dependent ~ predictor + (1|cluster), data = data,
                  cov.prior = custom(prior,
                  chol = FALSE,
                  common.scale = TRUE,
                  scale = "none"))
    
    temp <- data.frame(latestsigma = sigmastore,
                      varresid = as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))[2,4],
                      varclust = as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))[1,4])
    
    sigmascan <- rbind(sigmascan, temp)
    
    }
    
    head(sigmascan)
    #         sigma varresid     varclust
    #1 1.426974e-19 15.97006 2.278886e-18
    #2 9.323638e-02 15.18021 1.415348e+00
    #3 1.926383e-01 14.64654 2.821485e+00
    #4 2.926655e-01 14.28060 4.179438e+00
    #5 3.929266e-01 14.01496 5.506850e+00
    #6 4.932680e-01 13.81362 6.813817e+00
    
    #Plot the two-level variances as functions of the latest iterated sigmas (the assumed covariances of the random effects in the final models)

    plot(sigmascan$latestsigma, sigmascan$varclust, type = "l", col = "green", lwd = 5, xlab = "Latest iterated sigma", ylab = "Residual-variance est. (black); Cluster-variance est. (green)")
    lines(sigmascan$latestsigma, sigmascan$varresid, col = "black", lwd = 5)
    
    #The cluster-level variances can be almost perfectly solved by multiplying the latest iterated sigmas with residual variances. Here are the differences, which I think are rounding errors.
    
    sigmascan$latestsigma*sigmascan$varresid - sigmascan$varclust
    # [1] -3.851860e-34  2.220446e-16 -4.440892e-16 -8.881784e-16  8.881784e-16
    # [6]  8.881784e-16 -1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
    #[11] -1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  3.552714e-15  3.552714e-15
    #[16] -3.552714e-15 -3.552714e-15  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  3.552714e-15
    #[21]  7.105427e-15

#Below we can see that the multiplication of the covariance with the other variance does not lead to the another variance, at least in general
set.seed(1)
randX <- rnorm(5, 0, 1)
randY <- rnorm(5, 0, 2)
var(randX) #0.9235968
var(randY) #1.789357
cov(randX, randY)*var(randX) #0.3311527
cov(randX, randY)*var(randY) #0.6415682



In the blme documentation, under the bmerDist-class > Prior Distributions > Covariance Priors > Custom chapter (page 6), the description of the common.scale argument didn't quite open to me. Now I noticed that under the blme > Details > Covariance Prior chapter (page 3) it is said about the default common.scale = TRUE that: "the prior is applied to the random effect covariance divided by the estimated residual variance". If I got it right, then I don't still understand how multiplying cov(r,c)/var(r) (the mentioned ratio) with var(r) gives var(c). However, with the default settings for custom() functions, the so called "random-effect covariance" (the sigma variable I believe) indeed seems to be a ratio of var(c)/var(r), why multiplying it with the var(r) gives var(c). As noted above, this is possibly implied in the documentation. It would be nice if some expert could elaborate this a little, or at least confirm my current conclusions.
Update. I believe that the fitted random-intercept-only models in the code example above were special cases, causing confusion with the term "covariance prior". In this case, there is only one random-effect second-level variance (for the cluster intercepts, the residual level here is irrelevant), why the covariance with non-existent counterpart would be absurd, not to mention a variance-covariance matrix (at least at the state of delivering the sigma variable for the penalty function). When I instead gave a random-intercept random-slope model for the blmer() and again outputted the sigma variable from the penalty function, then I got four values implying a 2x2 second-level random-effect matrix. Thus, with the random-intercept-only models and common.scale = TRUE the sigma variable is reduced to the ratio of var(c_intercept)/var(r). The crucial part of solving the confusion was to distinguish which level of random effects is relevant.
These are my hands-on observations so far. I am a practical learner, I want to test stuff on detailed level to avoid possible misunderstanding of sophisticated statistical literature.
